# Deleted iOS 9.3 update file

Tags: ios

I was having a lot of trouble installing iOS 9.3 on an iPad Air and after a bit of searching around I was advised to delete the update file and try to reinstall.

Having done this, I no longer have the option to try again. When I check for a software update I am notified that I am 'up to date' with 9.2.1

How do I get back the option to upgrade to 9.3?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted your phone yet?

Comment: It's an iPad I'm doing it on, but yeah, I've restarted it, performed a hard reset, everything. I'm sure Apple will release another update for iOS 9.3 fairy soon, so hopefully a new file will be created. I just wondered if there was a way to get back the one I just deleted. If not, I'll just carry on using 9.2.1 until then.

Comment: Apple fixed the problem today. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple yanked iOS 9.3](https://ipsw.me/updates) for almost all devices which means you can't install it.

Comment: This changed today. [It was rereleased](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/03/apple-pulls-ios-9-3-update-for-older-devices-following-activation-problems/).